# Generate Spring MVC controller from Swagger/OpenAPI

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi

Is there a way how to generate controller Spring MVC code from Swagger/OpenAPI specification?

I know Swagger can be generated from existing Spring code but is this possible the other way round ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible using [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) from the command line or using [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io).

Comment: "Yes it is possible" is not an answer, you should provide where did you saw it without just giving a reference to the whole swagger codegen. I don't know why @dev-null accepted this answer.

Comment: Im not sure what further elaboration is required here @Vishrant. These are links to the tools that can be used to generate an implementation from a given specification. If you really think about it this is not a stack overflow/programming question at all.

Comment: Using Swagger is not recommended: "First, the code that was generated for me is using Java 7 and Spring Boot 1.5.22, both of which are quite outdated.

Second, if we make a change to the specification (and changes happen all the time), we’d have to copy-and-paste the files that were changed manually."
See this blog: https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-openapi/

Comment: Swagger issue to watch: (How do I generate code for Java 8 version?): https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/11158

Answer (score 8):

You are basically looking for generation of swagger server-side code. If you would like to generate it while you are building your application and if you are using maven you can use the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${swagger.codegen.version}</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <inputSpec>${swagger.yaml.file}</inputSpec>
      <language>spring</language>
      <configOptions>
        <sourceFolder>${swagger.generated.sourcepath}</sourceFolder>
        <!-- <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly> -->
        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
      </configOptions>
      <typeMappings>
        <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=Instant</typeMapping>
      </typeMappings>
      <importMappings>
        <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.Instant</importMapping>
      </importMappings>
      <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.swagger.model</modelPackage>
      <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.swagger.api</apiPackage>
      <invokerPackage>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.swagger.invoker</invokerPackage>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Please note the commented part `interfaceOnly` if set to true, it will only create the APIs class with default as `NOT_IMPLEMENTED` and you would have to write the implementation.

Add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger.annotations.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I used the following properties:

```
<properties>
    <swagger.codegen.version>2.4.1</swagger.codegen.version>
    <swagger.yaml.file>${project.basedir}/swagger.yaml</swagger.yaml.file>
    <swagger.annotations.version>1.5.21</swagger.annotations.version>
    <swagger.generated.sourcepath>src/main/java</swagger.generated.sourcepath>
</properties>
```

The other static approach that would require the generation of controller manually when there is a change in the swagger file would be to use [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).

[image]

Comment: Does this generate Spring MVC or JAX_RS code?