# Generating RestClient stubs from Swagger OpenAPI in Spring Boot with Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, swagger

Opposite of: [Generate Spring MVC controller from Swagger/OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104469/generate-spring-mvc-controller-from-swagger-openapi)

I *need* to integrate my Spring Boot project with a remote server exposing Swagger OpenApis. I can successfully download the `swagger.json` descriptor from the service, but I *would like* some automated help in generating REST stubs for a number of Java methods. I am using Gradle. I prefer to commit the `swagger.json` into my project to both be able to build offline (the remote services aren't exposed) and leverage Gradle's input caching.

So far I could leverage [Swagger generator for Gradle](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin) to do the biggest part of work.

I could try

```
apply plugin: 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator'

dependencies {
    swaggerCodegen 'io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli:3.0.5'  // or Swagger Codegen V3
    swaggerCodegen 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:3.3.4'     // or OpenAPI Generator
}

swaggerSources {
    remoteservice{
        inputFile = file("${project.rootDir}/gradle/swagger-remoteservice.json")
        code {
            language = 'spring'
        }
    }
}
```

The output was a fully fledged Gradle Spring Boot project in `build/swagger-code-remoteservice` also containing a Spring Boot executable.

I had to copy the parts I was interested to:

- DTOs. All of them generated automagically That is the biggest part I mentioned
- The `*Api` interface

Then I had to implement a Spring service leveraging RestTemplate to perform the Swagger operations. Since there are a number of operations to perform, it will take time.

Additional code I had to write

```
public class ApiRestImpl implements Api, InitializingBean {


    private RestOperations restTemplate;


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
             ... //authorization
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Item> getById(Integer id, Boolean bool) {
        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(properties.getUrl() + "/api/v1/Items/{id}")
                .queryParam("bool", bool
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(
                uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                Item.class,
                id
        );
    }

}
```

### What I'd like to do

I would like to be generated a fully (or almost fully) working client, possibly based on `RestTemplate`. Something I can integrate in my own calling code to perform the REST operation.

I could see that Spring Boot projects use a `build/generated` directory that gets included into the classpath

In this case, I don't like controllers to be generated and eventually scanned at runtime, so I had to copy the output to the source directory.

Comment: No, I didn't. This means your comment is *worth* an answer. I'll call this a day and try tomorrow

Comment: I just transformed it into an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [OpenAPI gradle plugin](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/#gradle). The [`java` client generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/) has a library option "`resttemplate`".